# Why jQuery is not working on the printed-element via PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrapvalidator

I tried validation on HTML element which get printed via PHP but it is not working, but it does work when I put the same HTML without PHP.

Below is the HTML in which the actual data will be printed via AJAX:

```
<div class="row" id="live_data">
    // here will all radio buttons and images echo via ajax
</div>
```

Here is the AJAX:

```
function fetch_all() {
      var form_name = 'package_form2';
       $.post('ajax/ajax_form_get_all_packages.php',{form_name:form_name}, function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            $('#live_data').html(result);
        });    
} fetch_all();
```

Here is the actual data which gets echoed via Ajax:

```
$output .= '
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="'.$id.'">
                <img src="uploads/'.$img.'" class="img-responsive">
            </label>
            <div>
                <div class="radio text-center">
                <input type="radio" id="'.$id.'" value="'.$code.'" name="optradio" class="optradio">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ';
```

Here is the code of FormValidation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu1_info').formValidation({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        icon: {
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {

            optradio: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please choose one of the Package'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
            // Prevent form submission
            e.preventDefault();

            // Get the form instance
            var $form = $(e.target);

            // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
            var fv = $form.data('formValidator');


        $form.bootstrapValidator('disableSubmitButtons', false);

        });   
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no element with class `optradio` in your markup. Instead there is one with attribute `name` equal to `optradio`:

```
$(document).on('change', '[name="optradio"]', function() {
    alert("Radio button clicked");
});
```

**UPDATE**

If I understood correctly, `#menu1_info` element comes from the ajax response

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu1_info').formValidation({
```

Here you are trying to select an element on document ready, but this element is **not present** to the DOM yet because it is appended **asynchronously** (after document ready event).

So, you have to initialize your plugin after the target element is present to the DOM (in the ajax callback function).

```
// The $('#menu1_info') element is not present now
$.ajax({
   url: '...',
   ...,
   success: function(data) {
      // Append data from ajax call
      $('#target').append(data);
      // Now, $('#menu1_info') element is present
      $('#menu1_info').formValidation({ ... });
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much, you solution is correct, I edited my question, can you also please tell me what's the reason BootstrapValidator doesn't work on element which get print by PHP

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to select an element that does not exist (no element with class 'optradio' exists).

Comment: BootstrapValidator get elements by name so it should work just by name element, but it is not working on name :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no such element in the response `'.optradio'`.

Better to change to this:

```
$('#live_data').on('change', ':radio', function() {
    alert("Radio button clicked");
});
```

Also you can delegate to closest static parent which in your case is `#live_data`

Comment: Hi thank you so much, this solution works perfectly, I edited my quesion, can you also please tell me how to solve it, its from the same html